# Should you use em/rem or px when extending foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm building a new web app with foundation 5.x and I've noticed everything seems to be based on rem. Previously I'd modify padding/margins using px but it seems like building a theme with foundation might be an easier when using a consistent rem like measurement.

Can anyone confirm (from experience) that building themes/ writing scss to extend foundation 5 is better with rem/em/px ?

Also should you use rem/em/px for font-sizes?

Comment: I suggest using rem to keep things consistent and have px fall back if you want to support IE8(simple tool-http://pleeease.io/play/). http://caniuse.com/#search=rem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529211/using-rem-units-for-a-div-in-a-web-page/24529402#24529402..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

em is relative to its parent, so this can get kind of confusing with the math.  If you have an li which is sized at 1.2em and nest another li inside it, it effectively gets a font-size of 1.2 × 1.2 = 1.44em.

rem is not relative to its parent, but to the root of the documnet (default of 16px). However, keep in mind rem is not supported by IE < 9.

Here's a codepen to illustrate this: http://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/DijuC

```
html {font-size: 120%}

.one li {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.two li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```